How can I build native images for multiple architectures with Spring Boot?
I need to build native images for my Spring Boot app for both linux/amd64 and linux/arm64 architecture. Following documentation at GraalVM Native Images I'm able to run:
mvn spring-boot:build-image -Pnative

and get a linux/arm64 image (on Apple M1). Ultimately I need to build an image for both linux/amd64 and linux/arm64 and push them to Docker Hub (on a GitHub Action CI/CD workflow), but I can't figure out how to do so with Spring Boot.
How can I build native images for multiple architectures with Spring Boot?
Note: I'm able to use buildx to build multi platform images, this question is specifically about how to build a native executable with Spring Boot for the Spring Boot application and package it to a container image.

Spring Boot 3.4 (currently available as a release candidate, scheduled to be released in late Nov 2024) has a new imagePlatform option that allows you to specify the architecture of the CNB builder image used for generating a Docker image with spring-boot:build-image. When using the default Paketo builder for Java apps, you can set the value of this parameter to linux/amd64 and linux/arm64, since that Paketo builder supports both of those architectures.
Note that choosing an architecture that is different from the architecture of the host will only work when the host can emulate the other architecture (as with Rosetta on macOS).

Thanks, I'll try that! Is it possible to build and push native images for multiple platforms at the same time (like with buildx)? I'm looking for the recommended practice to build native images with Spring Boot in CI/CD.

After extensive research, looks like to me it's not possible to build and push a multi platform image with Spring Boot (as it is with buildx). I can build images for both platforms with different tags, push them individually, then create and tag a single multi platform manifest but then I have three different tags in the registry while with buildx a single tag is pushed. Would be great to achieve the same with Spring Boot!

That is correct. This is not a limitation of Spring Boot as much as it is a limitation of the Cloud Native Buildpacks design. I think the discussion you are having in this GitHub issue thread is worth posting here for context: https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot/issues/491#issuecomment-2491569221
